# Java Stream iterate is not working with a predicate when doing a check for even-odd

Tags: java, lambda, functional-programming, java-stream, predicate

I am trying to create a Stream of even integer using Stream.iterate where I will pass a Predicate to check for even and an Unary operator.

```
        Stream<Integer> stream = Stream.iterate(0, s-> ((s<10) && (s%2==0)),  s-> s+1);
        stream.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Problem is it is just printing 0.

If I remove the even check s%2==0. It is printing number from 0-9

```
        Stream<Integer> stream = Stream.iterate(0, s-> (s<10),  s-> s+1);
        stream.forEach(System.out::println);
```

If I remove the s<10 and just keep the s%2==0 and put a limit. Still I only get 0 as output.

```
        Stream<Integer> stream = Stream.iterate(0, s-> (s%2==0),  s-> s+1);
        stream.limit(10).forEach(System.out::println);
```

I am not able to understand where I am going wrong. I know I can achieve this with filter but the point is I am not able to identify my mistake and with Lambda I am not able to debug in eclipse.

Comment: I think you might be confusing the predicate with a filter. It's not a filter it's a condition to continue. Just like in a for loop `for (int i = 0; i < 10 && i%2 == 0; i++)` this for loop would do just the first iteration.

Comment: If you're just trying to generate even integers, why not start with just evens? `IntStream.generate(0, i -> i + 2)`. The second parameter to `Stream#generate` in this case will terminate the stream when it returns `false` (e.g. for 1). Then you could keep the generator as-is with the upper bound: `Stream.iterate(0, s -> s < 10, s -> s + 2);` (or use `IntStream#range*`)

Comment: Ok so my understanding was incorrect. I thought predicate would be applied to each element instead once it returns false it stops. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ihe second parameter is called hasNext, so if s is 1 the prdicate return false and the iteration stops.

Use:

```
  IntStream.range(0,10).filter(s-> s%2==0).forEach(System.out::println);
```

it will print:

```
0
2
4
6
8
```

Comment: Ok so my understanding was incorrect. I thought predicate would be applied to each element instead once it returns false it stops. Thanks @Jens

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with iterate, in this way.

**Code:**

```java
Stream<Integer> stream = Stream.iterate( 0, s -> s < 10, s -> s + 1 )
        .filter( s -> ( s % 2 ) == 0 );

stream.forEach( System.out::println );
```

**Output:**

```
0
2
4
6
8
```